# Creating objects in for loop. I missing the mark a bit

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a for loop create objects as the children of a parent object. Usually, I would declare the object without using the for loop like this:

```
 var mObj = {};
 mObj.obj1 = {};
 mObj.obj2 = {};
 mObj.obj3 = {};
 mObj.obj3.firstname = "john";
 mObj.obj3.lastname = "superfly";
```

Now lets say I would like to employ a for loop to create the children objects of a parent object "mObj".

This is where I am going wrong:

```
var mArr = ["firstname","lastname","email"]; // This array holds the keys for the   objects

 var mObj = {};

 var len = (mArr.length);

 for(var i=0; i<len; i++){

      var obj+i = {}
      mObj = obj+i;
      mObj.obj + i.mArr[i] = ""

    }
```

So the outcome of this would be:

```
 mObj.obj1.firstname = "";
 mObj.obj2.lastname = "";
 mObj.obj3.email = "";
```

I just cannot seem to name the object with counter that is being created within for loop like:

```
obj1
obj2
obj3
```

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var obj+i = {}` is invalid syntax.

Try this:

```
mObj['obj' + i] = {};
```

If i == 1, this gives
    mObj['obj1'] = {};

Which is equiavlent to:

```
mObj.obj1
```

But when constructing dynamically, you have to use the

```
mObj['obj' + i]
```

Formatting.

Comment: thanks a lot. After some elbow grease, I got it going. I spend hours trying things out that darn . syntax was throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mArr = ["firstname","lastname","email"],
    mObj = {},
    len  = (mArr.length),
    i    = 0;

 for(; i<len; i++){
      myObj['obj' + i] = {}
      myObj['obj' + i].mArr[i] = ""
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the bracket syntax to assign a dynamic variable. For example:

```
var sampleObj = {};

for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    sampleObj["obj" + j] = { test: j };
}
```

This should produce the following object:

```
{
    "obj1" : { test: 1 },
    "obj2" : { test: 2 },
    "obj3" : { test: 3 }
}
```

After running the loop then, you could validly use this statement:

```
var testVal = sampleObj.obj1.test;
```

Comment: var keyArr = ["firstname","lastname","email"]
var valArr = ["John","Superfly","jsuperfly@yahoo.com"];

    mObj = {},
    len  = (mArr.length),
    i    = 0;

 for(; i<len; i++)
 {
      mObj['obj' + i] = {};
      mObj['obj' + i][mArr[i]] = valArr[i];
  }


console.log(mObj.obj2.email);